# GWT SimplePager : How to provide GoTo Functionality in pager?

Tags: java, gwt, pager, gwt-2.2-celltable

I am usign GWT2.3.
We developed CustomPager by overriding SimplePager.

We override createText() method such a way that we are showing string like "Page 1 of 4" using following code

```
    public String createText() {
        if(searchRecordCount%pageSizeForText == 0){
            totalPages = searchRecordCount/pageSizeForText;
        }else{
            totalPages = (searchRecordCount/pageSizeForText) + 1;
        }
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getFormat("#,###");
        return "Page "+formatter.format(this.getPage()+1) + " of " + formatter.format(totalPages);
      }
```

[image]

Now I want to use TextBox for CurrentPage so that user can enter page Number in textBox. (Functionality GoTo entered pageNumber)

createText() returns string so I cant user textBox ;) + Can't provide css

How can I do this ? Is there any way to solve this problem? Workaround if any or Sample code

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways how to achieve this:

1.) **Use HTML code to create a TextBox**:

In the `createText()` function you can create the textbox manually by using HTML code (better use [SafeHTML templates](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml.html) for avoiding XSS):

```
String textbox_str = "<input type='textbox' name='goto'>";
```

However you have to write code for handling the actual event (i.e. ChangeEvent) and call `setPage()` of your SimplePager using JSNI.

2.) **Add TextBox widget to SimplePager and override constructor**:

[SimplePager](http://www.google.com/codesearch#A1edwVHBClQ/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/SimplePager.java&q=SimplePager%20package%3ahttp://google-web-toolkit%5C.googlecode%5C.com&type=cs) is basically a Composite which adds ImageButtons in its constructor for  the forward and backward links.
You can extend SimplePager add a TextBox and override the constructor to add the TextBox between the forward and backward ImageButtons.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In #1 answer: How n where to add SafeHtmlTemplates in createText() ?

Comment: Use either ``SaveHTMLBuilder`` or a ``SaveHTMLTemplate``. See [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml.html#Creating_SafeHtml_Values) fore more details.

Comment: createText() method called from onRangeOrRowCountChanged() and output of createText() set as string not html in SimplePager.java :( i.e. html_label.setText(createText()); There should be htmlLabel.setHtml("...html or string.")

Comment: How to add a textbox between the forward and backward buttons.

Comment: `panel.add(new TextBox())` with panel being a `FlowPanel` for example.

Comment: will that add the textbox in between forward and backward image buttons?

Comment: Your second suggestions works like a charm. Overrode `onLoad` instead and added my `TextBox` using `((HorizontalPanel) getWidget()).insert(textBox, 2)` to make it appear in the middle (assuming that you use 4 buttons).